# Understanding Django exclude queryset on ForeignKey relationship

Tags: django, django-models

Really struggling to explain this one. I have the following models

```
class Star(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255, unique=True)

class Image(models.Model):
    star = models.ForeignKey(Star, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='images')
    status = models.BooleanField(verbose_name="Show online", default=True)
```

With the following data

Star table

| star | name | slug |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Star 1 | star-1 |
| 2 | Star 2 | star-2 |

Image table

| star | status |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | False |
| 1 | True |
| 2 | True |
| 2 | False |

I then have the following query to grab a  single star object with all the associated images with a status of True.

```
    star = Star.objects.filter(slug=slug).exclude(images__status=False).get()
```

However this  retunrs DoesNotExist exception, despite images with a status of true existing. Can anybody explain this? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`exclude` along a one-to-many relationship excludes items if any of their related objects match the condition. That is, you've said "get me a star object with this slug, but make sure it doesn't have any images with status False". And your example data does have an image with status False for both star objects. If you just want to get one that has an image with status `True`, use `filter(image__status=True)`.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. What happens if I want to get a star when no images have a status of True?  Using Star.objects.filter(slug=slug).filter(images__status=True).get() returns DoesNotExist exception in this case.

Comment: In that case you'd exclude on `True` - just negate your original query. On a one-to-many, `exclude` means "none can match these filters" while `filter` means "at least one must match these filters"